# ways to implement mysql row constraint

Tags: mysql, datetime, row, constraints

Does anyone know if its possible to implement a row constraint in MySQL?

Lets say i have a very simple table for maintaining promotion codes for a webshop:

```
CREATE TABLE `promotioncodes` (
  `promotionid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `promotioncode` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `partnerid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `nr_of_usage` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `valid_from` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `valid_through` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`promotionid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `promotioncode_unique` (`promotioncode`)
)
```

Is there any way to **make sure** that when a row gets inserted or updated:

1) The 'valid_from' date is always 'smaller' (in terms of dates) then 'valid_through'.

2) If 'valid_from' happens to be left blank/null 'valid_through' must be blank/null too.

3) If 'valid_through' happens to be left blank/null 'valid_from' must be blank/null too.

I readed some stuff about triggers and stored procedures but i dont have the feeling these are the solution :/ ? If they are the solution then please give me a concrete example of how to implement this

Comment: It might be possible with a stored procedure, but I couldn't promise it.  MySQL isn't so hot at such things as other more robust databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create stored procedure that will insert data. In this stored procedure you can implement any rules which you need.

Here is the example.

```
create procedure promotioncodes_insert(
  IN...  list of params
  OUT error_code
)
exec:begin
  set error_code = 0; -- everything is ok

  if valid_from > valid_thru then
    set error_code = -1; -- error
    leave exec;
  end if;

  if (valid_from is null) and (valid_thru is not null) then
    set error_code = -2; -- another kind of error
    leave exec;
  end if;

  -- and so on

  -- doing insert

end;
```

Please note that if you will do direct insert like `insert into promocodes() values()` these constraints will not work.

Comment: Ok thanks for you're reply. But if i understand correct this is only possible through a stored proc?

Comment: It's the right way to do it. Also, you can add fake column to your table (fake_status tinyint(1) not null). Implement insert/update triggers with your restrictions. If data is not passing your restrictions you will set `fake_status = NULL` that will cause the data will not inserted at all with exception that you should handle inside application. But it is completely evil.